# Como almacenar en una tabla la información de Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Quisiera almacenar la información que obtengo a través de un Store Procedure, el SP que tengo envían información a un correo utilizando el `sp_send_dbmail` a través de un formulario de contacto, ahora lo que quiero es almacenar dicha información.

El Store Procedure que captura la información obtenida en el formulario y que envía correo es el siguiente.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Formulario] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
    @name varchar(100),
    @surname varchar(100),
    @Phone varchar(100),
    @Email varchar(100),
    @Category int,
    @NameCategory varchar(100),
    @Subject varchar(100),   
    @Message varchar(200)
    --
    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sStr1      NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Subject1   VARCHAR(250),
            @Correo     varchar(50)
    
    if (@Category = 1)
        select @Correo ='john.doe@stackoverflow.com'
    
    Select @Subject1 = 'Asunto prueba'
            SELECT @sStr1 ='<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                     
            </head>
            <body>
            
            </body>
            </html>'            
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'Perfil prueba', 
            @recipients = @Correo,          
            @subject = @Subject1,
            @body  = @sStr1,
            @body_format = 'HTML'
END
```

Recapitulando nuevamente lo que quisiera almacenar en una tabla nueva y lo que me interesa son los parámetros que se añaden al comienzo del SP

```
@name varchar(100),
    @surname varchar(100),
    @Phone varchar(100),
    @Email varchar(100),
    @Category int,
    @NameCategory varchar(100),
    @Subject varchar(100),   
    @Message varchar(200)
```

Realmente desconozco que se pueda almacenar la información que se obtiene en un Store Procedure.

Comment: El SP es un bloque de código T-SQL. Dentro de él puedes consultar, manipular y hacer operaciones DML con los datos que estés operando. Así pues, un INSERT / UPDATE común y corriente va a funcionar (con la sintaxis adecuada).

Comment: @Alfabravo Algún ejemplo que me puedas aportar como respuesta para darle validez ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tal como te comento Alfabravo el sp es una sentencia T-SQL por lo cual tu podrías poner IF,Ciclos,etc, en este caso necesitas hacer un insert y la manera seria como normalmente haces un insert te deje un ejemplo con lo tuyo pero dejando el insert al final
Si necesitas validar campos y ese tipo de cosas igual podrias

Saludos.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Formulario] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
    @name varchar(100),
    @surname varchar(100),
    @Phone varchar(100),
    @Email varchar(100),
    @Category int,
    @NameCategory varchar(100),
    @Subject varchar(100),   
    @Message varchar(200)
    --
    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sStr1      NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Subject1   VARCHAR(250),
            @Correo     varchar(50)
    
    if (@Category = 1)
        select @Correo ='john.doe@stackoverflow.com'
    
    Select @Subject1 = 'Asunto prueba'
            SELECT @sStr1 ='<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                     
            </head>
            <body>
            
            </body>
            </html>'            
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'Perfil prueba', 
            @recipients = @Correo,          
            @subject = @Subject1,
            @body  = @sStr1,
            @body_format = 'HTML'

--Insertamos los datos a la tabla
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTable](name,surname,Phone...) VALUES (@name,@surname,@Phone...)
END
```

Comment: Respuesta clara y concisa